# How do I connect netopeer2 to sample localhost on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-20.04

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

All components of netopeer2 is intalled by following this [website](http://www.seguesoft.com/index.php/netconfc/free-trial-netconfc/2-uncategorised/1-setup-netopeer2). I don't know how to configure netopeer2 server username or password. I install all the components and try the following steps.

I start the netopeer2 server with this command:

[image: Server start]

I check the netopeer2 server:

[image: Server check]

Then I try to connect netopeer2 server:

[image: Connection attempt]

Comment: Please provide all necessary information here.  No one wants to look at 4 links in order to help you !!